# What is the 1977 Wow signal?

Tags: astronomy, radio

Can someone explain about the [1977 Wow signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow!_signal)? I know that it is a signal received from space in 1977, in the form of a series of code "6EQUJ5". I would like to know if there is any thing or event which can generate this signal other than an intelligent life form? If yes then can you tell me which things or events can generate it??

Comment: You might wanna ask this at [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Somebody's been reading Cracked.com...

Comment: The "code" is just the way the instrument being used recorded variations in the radio signal intensity. 6EQUJ5 is an increasing, then decreasing signal intensity. Also, which scientists are excited about this? Or do you mean that this observation generated some excitement back in the 1970s?

Answer (score 11):

Did you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow!_signal)?  It explains the signal rather well, I think.  At any rate, it is called the Wow! signal because, as the picture shows someone wrote Wow! in the margin.

[image: Wow!]

As for the code and why they were excited, I quote the Wikipedia article,

> The circled alphanumeric code **6EQUJ5** describes the intensity variation of the signal. A space denotes an intensity between 0 and 1, the numbers 1 to 9 denote the correspondingly numbered intensities (from 1.000 to 10.000), and intensities of 10.0 and above are denoted by a letter ('A' corresponds to intensities between 10.0 and 11.0, 'B' to 11.0 to 12.0, etc.). The value 'U' (an intensity between 30.0 and 31.0) was the highest detected by the radio telescope; on a linear scale it was over 30 times louder than normal deep space.

A very powerful anomalous signal?  Yeah, that's pretty exciting, especially when you're looking for a powerful, anomalous signal.  There's some other information there, such as the fact that the length of the signal was exactly what they expected to see for an ET signal, so I'd go read it.

Is this proof of intelligent life elsewhere?  Nope.  It was cool, but nobody could find it again.  Odds are, it was something from here.  Again, the article explains a few of those.  People like to think that it means something, and who knows, maybe it does, but without repeated observations it's largely meaningless and is simply an interesting footnote.

Comment: Then again if you are a budget/energy conscious alien civ and you want to maximize your chances of making contact for minimum cost you don't spend all your time broadcasting at a particular planet. Rather you go from one candidate to the next without spending too long broadcasting to a single one. Whose knows how long it takes for the cycle to repeat, if at all. Depends on the number of candidates, political will (there are alien mouths to feed, after all...) etc. Not proof of civilization of course. Not even close. But it's not crazy to think an ET signal would never be repeated.

Comment: You're correct, but repetition could be a hallmark separating activity from background, such as this.  If this signal had regularly repeated itself 16 times and then disappeared, it would be a whole different ballgame.

Comment: I'm pretty confused about when they say it's "exactly the length they expected". From what I can make out, it sounds like the duration comes from the rate at which their telescope scanned across the sky, so a point source would be in their observable window for 72 seconds, and would peak in a certain way. I can't see *any* evidence against this being some burst from a naturally occurring radio point source. Do I have a plausible source for such a signal? Well, a few things come to mind before I start considering ALIENS! but I don't know enough to speculate too much...

Comment: @Kyle, maybe just a spy satellite pointing the wrong way! :)

Comment: @udiboy Doubt it, spy satellite would be moving across the sky unless it was in geostationary orbit, so the duration would be different. And I think the observation location is inconsistent with a geostationary orbit.

Comment: Is it possible that there was repetition within that "single" 6-character sequence? (ie, that the sampling rate was too low to let us see several separated signals being emitted?) (in other word, that we only see a "blur" of the **possibly-intermittent-or-repeating** signal?)